# Textacular Fuzzy Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, haml, ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to implement [the textacular gem](https://github.com/textacular/textacular) in my Rails 4 App. Basic and Advanced Search work fine, but when I try to implement Fuzzy Search, I encounter some trouble.

### Installation Instructions from the Repository:

> Finally, the #fuzzy_search method lets you use Postgres's trigram
>   search funcionality.
>
> In order to use this, you'll need to make sure your database has the
>   pg_trgm module installed. On your development machine, you can require
>   textacular/tasks and run
>
> rake textacular:install_trigram
>
> Depending on your production environment, you might be able to use the
>   rake task, or you might have to manually run a command. For Postgres
>   9.1 and above, you'll want to run
>
> CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

---

### What I've Tried

I tried running `rake textacular:install_trigram` and `bundle exec rake textacular:install_trigram` in the root directory of my app and I get this message:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/share/postgresql/extension/pg_trgm.control
rake aborted!
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "pg_trgm"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
: CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `exec'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/textacular-3.1.0/lib/textacular/postgres_module_installer.rb:54:in `install_postgres_91_module'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/textacular-3.1.0/lib/textacular/postgres_module_installer.rb:7:in `install_module'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/textacular-3.1.0/lib/textacular/tasks.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => textacular:install_trigram
```

---

Based on this, I tried `sudo rake textacular:install_trigram` and I got this:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/ssapra/Sameet/Programming/WebDev/Rails/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ssapra/Sameet/Programming/WebDev/Rails/myapp/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ssapra/Sameet/Programming/WebDev/Rails/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/ssapra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

Lastly, after reading the *For Postgres 9.1 and above*, I tried running `psql` and then `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`. No errors (although anytime I do it now, it will tell me it already exists). So I `\quit` and then replace my line of code that does work:

```
@search = Content.advanced_search(params[:search].split(" ").join("|")).basic_search(params[:search])
```

*with:*

```
@search = Content.fuzzy_search(title: params[:search]).fuzzy_search(text: params[:search])
```

*or even:*

```
 @search = Content.fuzzy_search(params[:search])
```

and I get this:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying % unknown
LINE 1: ...NT(*) FROM "contents"  WHERE (("contents"."title" % 'inv')) ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contents"  WHERE (("contents"."title" % 'inv')) AND (("contents"."text" % 'inv'))
```

It gets stuck on the first line:

```
-if @contents.empty?
       %p="No results found for: #{@query}"
-elsif !@query.empty?
       %p="Your search results for: #{@query}"
```

### Contents Controller

In my `contents_controller.rb`:
I have these three additions:

```
require 'textacular'
require 'textacular/tasks'
ActiveRecord::Base.extend(Textacular)
```

I am running Postgres 9.2.4. Any ideas?

Comment: Here there. I'm having this same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I did not unfortunately. :(

Comment: create the extension logged in as the postgres user. Before that, you should install postgresql-contrib (using oses package manager, for instance, apt in case of debian forks) module.